# Orbeon:Set default value for app

Tags: java, orbeon, xforms

Orbeon form builder:
in new mode,How can i set default value for "app".
I try to do it in dialog-form-setting.xpl.But it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to only be able to create forms in a certain app, you don't need to change `dialog-form-setting.xpl` but instead can just update the [`form-builder-permissions.xml`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/access-control#TOC-Access-to-specific-apps-forms-in-Form-Builder) to include:

```
<role name="*" app="myapp" form="*"/>
```

where `myapp` is the app you want to restrict users to. And of course, through this configuration file, you can make that restriction more granular, on per-role basis.